# Paypal subscription with guest user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I want to use PayPal Recurring subscription with Guest Checkout users. I'm using this https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring gem. It's working fine without guest login. So how can i set SOLUTIONTYPE or allow_guest in this gem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in PayPal called "Enhanced Recurring Payments", this is for guest checkout option for subscription payments. This option needs to enable in your PayPal account. [Click here](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/us-erp-full) for more information about Enhanced Recurring Payments.

In order to enable Enhanced Recurring Payments option in your PayPal account, you will need to contact PayPal customer service team for further help.

Comment: Okay. But i'm using sandbox.

Comment: So how can i configure guest checkout true or false in gem configuration.

Comment: Sorry.. Enhanced Recurring Payments is only for PayPal website payment standard buttons. The Given SDK URL shows the Express Checkout integration. You will need to upgrade the sandbox account to PRO, then use [PayPal Pro recurring payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/recurring-payments/) integration for receiving direct card recurring payments.